# using templates with function pointer arguments

Tags: templates, function, pointers

I was wondering how to use a template with a function pointer as an argument. For instance,

```
template<typename T> someFunction(T /*?*/) {}
```

where T is a function pointer (e.g. `void (*)(int,int*,double)` )

I want to use this to bypass the difference issue for function pointers of two functions such as:

```
void function(int,int);
void class::function(int,int);
```

So, if function pointers don't work, is there another way?

Edit: Basically, I need to make a function that accepts a variety of functions by using a template (just as a regular template function accepts a variety of variables).

Comment: You cannot "bypass the difference". A member function doesn't make any sense without an accompanying instance. Also, `class` is a reserved word in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Member function pointers are a different beast than function pointers, for instance there is an additional `this` argument for them. Its not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, sounds like Boost.Function/Bind would help. Note they are standard since TR1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use functors instead of pointers to member functions. An example:

```
class SomeFunctor {
public:
    void operator()(int i, int* ip, double d)
    {
    }
};

void someFunction(int i, int* ip, double d)
{
}

template<typename T>
void doSomething(T f)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int* ip = &j;
    double d;

    f(i, ip, d);
}

SomeFunctor someFunctor;
doSomething(someFunctor);
doSomething(someFunction);
```

Note that I have not tested this code and therefore, some modifications may be needed to get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at std::function ; it's a generalized way of holding a "functor", which is something that you can call.
( See npclaudiu's response for an example of one kind of functor )

That being said, K-ballo is correct, a member function is different than a free function, because it requires an object.
This is typically implemented by having a hidden parameter passed in; you can refer to it as "this".

So when you write `void my_class::function(int,int);`

The compiler really generates `void my_class::function (my_class*,int,int);`

You can use std::bind to associate data and functions - to create functors on the fly.
The best tutorial that I know of is for [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html)